# Can Delphi 7 pass Int64 value through OLE Variant?

Tags: windows, delphi, activex, delphi-7, ole

I know that in Delphi 5 it is impossible to write Int64 to Variant and OLEVariant and so, to use it in Type Library (TLB) file of COM Server.

Does anybody know or had experience with Delphi 7 regarding of usage int64 values in COM Server interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No restriction on `Int64` in Delphi 7 variants: it is supported, in the standard way:

There is indeed the OLE/COM compatible type definition

```
varInt64    = $0014; { vt_i8          20 }
```

in the `System.pas` unit, and all needed conversion in the `Variants.pas` unit.

I confirm it was not supported in Delphi 5.